# Why when I delete item from list binds to component, it deletes the right item from the list but duplicated the last item

Tags: c#, components, blazor

I have a strange behavior in Blazor server app.

When I have a list of object and I delete one of the items in the list, it deletes the right item in the list but it copies the data from the last item to the one before it.

It only happen when I bind the list data to my own component.
If I bind it directly to an input element it wont happen.

I reproduce the behavior in a small code sample as follow, just try to delete the second item and see the behavior.

Thank for who may help ...

**Blazor markup**

```
 <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (User user in _users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><MyText @bind-Value="user.Id"></MyText></td>
                <td><MyText @bind-Value="user.Name"></MyText></td>
                <td @onclick="(() => DeleteUser(user))">delete</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Blazor Code**

```
private List<User> _users = new List<User>();
private class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = "";
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _users.Add(new User() { Id = "1", Name = "Adam" });
    _users.Add(new User() { Id = "2", Name = "Benny" });
    _users.Add(new User() { Id = "3", Name = "Charles" });
    _users.Add(new User() { Id = "4", Name = "David" });
    base.OnInitialized();
}

private void DeleteUser(User user)
{
    _users.Remove(user);
}
```

**MyText Component**

```
<input @bind-value="@Value" />

@code {

    public string _value = "";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_value != value)
            {
                _value = value;
                ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can't delete items in a foreach loop.
Create a second List<string> toDelete and fill it with the element you want to delete. Loop this second list and use _firstList.Remove(item).

Comment: @RemiTHOMAS - there is no "delete in a foreach loop" here.

Comment: Your code is bad. You shouldn't mutate or modify the Value parameter. The Value property should be automatic. It is used by the framework to pass values from a parent component to a child component, but you shouldn't manipulate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to help the 'diffing engine' of Blazor a little. Use `@key` like this:

```
@foreach (User user in _users)
{
    <tr @key="user">
        <td><MyText @bind-Value="user.Id"></MyText></td>
        <td><MyText @bind-Value="user.Name"></MyText></td>
        <td @onclick="(() => DeleteUser(user))">delete</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Henk, you were right !!!
It works either in the demo project as well in my production.

Comment: So thankful I found this. My symptoms were slightly different than the OP, but it solved my problem where if I had a list of 4 items, if I deleted item 1 it would be deleted from the collection, but the screen would delete item 4.